# Providing existing certificate secret for mailu helm chart

Tags: email, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using [mailu](https://github.com/Mailu/Mailu)'s [official helm chart](https://github.com/Mailu/helm-charts).

Let's say I don't want it to create a certificate from Let's Encrypt (NOT using cert-manager),
and/or I want to reuse an existing certificate.

For HTTP Ingress, it's easy.
I just have to specify `ingress.existingSecret`.

```yaml
        ingress:
          enabled: true
          existingSecret: <EXISTING_CERTIFICATE_AS_SECRET>
```

But for other protocols, like `imaps`, `pop3s`,  `smtps`(465), and `starttls`(587), how can I provide the certificate?

I thought volume mounts from secret should be configured,
but it seems the chart does not provide the feature.
I wonder if I understand correctly, and whether it's indeed a missing feature currently.

Thanks!